# Use Matrix API maps without taking traffic

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the Google Maps Matrix API, to estimate the distance between 2 points, the point is that it uses traffic as a parameter to suggest a route which ends up giving a distance greater than the average. And since my application is mainly present in smaller cities, drivers end up following other routes of their own, etc.

So in the Matrix API call I would just like to return the distance from the nearest route.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Google Maps API. I can see that the feature request has already been filed, but unfortunately rejected by Google:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35826943

Here is the answer of Google rep:

> The Google Maps API team has reviewed the request for returning the shortest routes for driving directions, as opposed to the fastest routes. After much consideration, we have decided to keep the existing behavior and not implement shortest routes.
>
> We understand there is demand for this feature; however, we believe that using the shortest route rather than the fastest route is not a good idea in practice. When the shortest route is not the fastest, it is likely to be a lower quality route in terms of time, fuel efficiency and sometimes even personal safety. We think these factors are more important to the majority of drivers on the road.
>
> Our primary goal with driving directions is to save time for drivers. Therefore, we do not plan to offer the shortest routes in Google Maps or the Directions API.
>
> There are a few workarounds that could potentially yield shorter routes, but we have found that they have significant drawbacks. We explain these below to clarify why we recommend against them.
>
> 1. Request routes in both directions. 
>      Directions from A to B may not yield a feasible route from B to A due to situations like one-way streets, turn restrictions and different locations of highway exits. Requesting routes in both directions and taking the shortest route may yield a route that is not usable in the one direction.
> 2. Request alternative routes. 
>      Adding alternatives=true to the request and picking the shortest route can yield a shorter route than that returned by default.
>
> However, these alternative routes are not generally stable (may change over time as short-term road conditions change) nor guaranteed to include the shortest route. This means that the shortest route may still not be available, and also the shortest route found by this approach may change over time, giving an impression of instability.